# How to count items by hours between a start time and an end time

Tags: r

I want to count the number of users using a system by hour intervals with data on login/logoff time.

Example data:

```r
login <- c("18:10:00", "19:05:06", "19:42:22", "20:22:11")
logoff <- c("20:45:21", "21:55:00", "19:55:00", "21:30:50")
df <- data.frame(login, logoff)
```

Desired output:

| Hour | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 18:00-19:00 | 1 |
| 19:00-20:00 | 3 |
| 20:00-21:00 | 3 |
| 21:00-22:00 | 2 |

Comment: What if someone logs in at 11pm and logs off at 1am? Does your data also contain the date or just the time?

Comment: Note also that your desired first column is ambiguous. What is with people who are logged in at axactly 19:00:00? Should they vount in 18-19 or 19-20?

Comment: @deschen Thanks for the heads up! The  hourly intervals in desired output should actually be in the format of 18:00 - 18:59.

Comment: Apart from this labeling of the hour column, does the solution provided work? If so, please accept it as an answer or flag it as helpful so that others can benefit from it as well.

Comment: @deschen Thanks! Just ran the code. It worked for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could start with:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(start = hour(hms(login)),
         end   = hour(hms(logoff)),
         ID    = 1:n(),
         hour  = start) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  complete(hour = start:end) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  count(hour) %>%
  mutate(hour = paste0(hour, ':00 - ', hour + 1, ":00"))
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  hour              n
  <chr>         <int>
1 18:00 - 19:00     1
2 19:00 - 20:00     3
3 20:00 - 21:00     3
4 21:00 - 22:00     2
```

Note: this does not yet account for login/offs going over the day end.

---

Update: here is a solution that does also work in case sessions stretch over the end of the day (see how I have changed the 4th value for logoff):

```
login <- c("18:10:00", "19:05:06", "19:42:22", "20:22:11")
logoff <- c("20:45:21", "21:55:00", "19:55:00", "00:30:50")
df <- data.frame(login, logoff)

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(start = hour(hms(login)),
         end   = hour(hms(logoff)),
         ID    = 1:n(),
         hour  = start) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  complete(hour = 0:23) %>%
  fill(c(start, end), .direction = "updown") %>%
  filter((min(start) <= max(end) & hour %in% min(start):max(end)) |
         (min(start) > max(end) & hour %in% c(min(start):23, 0:max(end)))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  count(hour) %>%
  mutate(hour = paste0(hour, ':00 - ', hour + 1, ":00"))
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  hour              n
  <chr>         <int>
1 0:00 - 1:00       1
2 18:00 - 19:00     1
3 19:00 - 20:00     3
4 20:00 - 21:00     3
5 21:00 - 22:00     2
6 22:00 - 23:00     1
7 23:00 - 24:00     1
```